# How to draw a diagram for "Rope Around the Earth" problem?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, draw, tikz-graphs

I would like to produce an image to help students to better understand the celebrated ``Rope Around the Earth'' problem, which asks---how much slack must be added to a tightly fitting rope around the earth's equator in order to uniformly elevate the rope 1 foot uniformly above the equator.

I would be grateful if someone suggest how to do this with the image of a circular cord (rope image, if possible) circumscribing a 2 (or three)-dimensional earth at the equator with the two radii labeled.

[image]

Comment: I added the photo from the old question so it's clearer for future visitors.

Comment: I've never used it but with metapost there is this [mp-geo](https://melusine.eu.org/syracuse/poulecl/mp-geo/) and with pstrick there is that [ctan pst-geo](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-geo)

Comment: @Alenanno Thank you for the edit, as well as for your excellent answer!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

So I tried to reproduce the graphics you posted but removing the circle around the Earth and using it to make the equator. Yes, it's a shaded sphere but its position is accurate, trust me.

If there is something unclear about the code, please feel free to ask so that it might help you if you decide to do more in TikZ.

You can replace the shaded sphere in the code with an actual image of Earth, but here I'm using this one as en example because I was not sure about matters of copyright. [Download here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbjOx.jpg)

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=10pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta}

\newcommand\earth{5cm} % the image's width/height
\newcommand\myclip{\earth/2-1.2pt} % clips the black borders from the sphere

\tikzset{%
    lbl/.style={text=black,anchor=west, at end}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) circle (\myclip);
    \node[inner sep=0, circle,opacity=.8] (earth) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\earth, keepaspectratio]{earth.jpg}}; % save the image in the same folder as this .tex file
    \draw[line width=1.5pt, yellow!40!orange] 
        ($(0,0)+(-\myclip-1pt,0)$) arc (180:360:2.5cm+1pt and 8mm);
    \end{scope}   
    \draw[line width=2pt] (0,0) circle (\myclip+1cm);

    \draw[line width=1pt,
        red, {Stealth[scale=1.5]}-{Stealth[scale=1.5]}]
            (80:\myclip+1.5mm) arc (80:25:\myclip+1.5mm) node[lbl] {$C_E$};
    \draw[line width=1pt,       
        violet,{Stealth[scale=1.5]}-{Stealth[scale=1.5]}]
            (80:\myclip+1.2cm) arc (80:25:\myclip+1.2cm) node[lbl] {$L_R$};

    \draw[line width=1pt] node[fill,inner sep=1pt, circle] at (earth) {}
        edge[red, -{Stealth[scale=1.5]}] node[lbl] {$R_E$} (290:\myclip) 
        edge[violet, -{Stealth[scale=1.5]}] node[lbl] {$R_R$} (320:\myclip+1cm) 
        ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I will put a true Earth following the answer into this link deleting the red borders :-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407751/make-a-border-around-a-circled-image/407752

Comment: @Alenanno Thank you again.

Answer (score 18):

Compile with [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.io/).

Step 1: Find an image in `svg` of earth on the internet!
Example: [an image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fa/Globe.svg)

Step 2: Convert it (from `svg` to `eps`), save as for example `Glose.eps`. Online tool like https://convertio.co/vn/svg-eps/.

Step 3: Create `asy` code and put `Glose.eps` in the same folder.

```
unitsize(1cm);

label(graphic("Globe.eps","width=5cm"),(0,0));
clip(scale(2.5)*unitcircle);
layer();

pair center=(0,0);

draw(scale(2.5)*unitcircle,linewidth(0.7bp));
draw(scale(3)*unitcircle,linewidth(0.7bp));

draw(scale(.7)*Label("$R_E$",EndPoint,black),center--center+2.5*dir(-65),red,Arrow);
draw(scale(.7)*Label("$R_R$",EndPoint,black),center--center+3*dir(-40),blue,Arrow);
draw(scale(.7)*Label("$C_E$",BeginPoint,black),arc(center,2.65,30,80),red,Arrows);
draw(scale(.7)*Label("$L_R$",BeginPoint,black),arc(center,3.15,30,80),blue,Arrows);
dot(center,linewidth(2bp));

shipout(bbox(2mm,invisible));
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: A good Asymptote answer \ _(+_+)_/  too!

Answer (score 11):

A PSTricks solution only for either fun or comparison purposes.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-geo}  
\psset
{
    Decran=9.6,
    path=C:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-geo/data,
}


\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \WorldMapThreeD[circles=false,blueEarth=true]
    \pscircle{4}
    \psset{linewidth=3pt,arrows=->,arrowinset=0}
    \psline[linecolor=blue](4;-40)
    \psline[linecolor=red](2.5;-70)
    \uput[-40](4;-40){$R_R$}
    \uput[-70](2.5;-70){$R_E$}
    \psset{arrows=<->}  
    \psarc[linecolor=blue](0,0){4.25}{10}{80}
    \psarc[linecolor=red](0,0){2.75}{10}{80}
    \uput[-60](4.25;10){$L_R$}
    \uput[-45](2.5;10){$C_E$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust the following to suit your preferences.

```
RotX=-45,
RotZ=-45,
PHI=45,
THETA=30,
```

Add them to the first `\psset`.

Comment: +1 Good PSTricks answer. :-(

Comment: You can visit [my blog](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c1213036)! I will show all my Asymptote knowledge in that blog. :-)))

Comment: @TrongVuong1998: You should add Google Adsense to make more money there!

Comment: It is a nonprofit blog! :-((

Comment: @TrongVuong1998: Make getting a profit as a side effect. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using LaTeX, you can also use Asymptote code to generate a graph. It is compatible with LaTeX, so you can use this code in a LaTeX interpreter.

[https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Asymptote_(Vector_Graphics_Language)#:~:text=Asymptote%20is%20a%20powerful%20vector,standard%20mathematics%20typesetting%20language%2C%20LaTeX](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Asymptote_(Vector_Graphics_Language)#:%7E:text=Asymptote%20is%20a%20powerful%20vector,standard%20mathematics%20typesetting%20language%2C%20LaTeX).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This already suggested TrongVuong1998. He also show how to draw this image with `asymptote` ...